# Need help for pointing out, source follower circuit with current source, designing NMOS

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, current-source, source-follower

[image]

I'm not sure did I solve this problem right.

I made \$ r_{o2} \$ , which is resistance looking at Q2 drain.
So I can get
$$ g_{m,Q3} = 1.8m(A/V) $$
from
$$A_v = \frac{r_{o2} || r_{o3}}{1/g_m + (r_{o2} || r_{o3})}$$

and I could get W/L by

$$ g_{m,Q3} = \sqrt{2I_D \mu C_{ox}(W/L)} $$
then
$$ (W/L)_{Q3} = 16.2 $$

And I can find out \$ V_{GS} = 0.8V , V_{GS} = V_{DS}\$ at Q1

so

$$I_{REF} = 1/2 \mu C_{ox}(W/L)_{Q1}(V_{GS}-V_T)^2(1+ \lambda V_{DS})$$

then I get
$$ (W/L)_{Q1} = 20.576 $$
and I can guess (W/L)*{Q2} = (W/L)*{Q1} because their \$V_{GS}, V_{DS}\$ is same.

I know in Q2
$$g_m = \frac{2I_D}{V_{GS}-V_T} = \mu C_{ox}(W/L)(V_{GS}-V_T) $$

But this equation is not true when I substitute my values. What's the problem?

Comment: While I think this could be a "good" homework question because it shows your work and allows someone to help point out where you went wrong, I think the title desperately needs to be revised.

Comment: @JYelton Do you have some idea about that??

Comment: You need to treat the current mirror Q1, Q2 separately from Q3. Determine W/L of Q1 and Q2 such that \$I_{REF}\$ is flowing. Now you can determine the output resistance \$r_{o}\$ of Q2. Then we know that small signal equivalent of the current mirror: an ideal current source with value  \$I_{REF}\$ and a resistor \$r_{o2}\$ in parallel with it. Now draw the small signal equivalent circuit of Q3 and use the model of the mirror connected to its source.

Comment: if the gain is 0.9 you need to have ro2||ro3 = 9*gm3

Comment: The gain of 0.9 V/V is the result of the output impedance of the source follower (roughly 1/gm) and \$r_{o2}\$, these make a voltage divider. From \$r_{o2}\$ determine what the output impedance of the source follower needs to be. Then you know what the gm of Q3 needs to be, from that determine W/L (you know the biasing current already).